# Where can I change the Authentication Error Messages in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want the translate the error messages popping up at login/registration in Laravel, messages such as this: 
[Capture of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0VNW.png)

But I can't find the location of these messages. Where are they?

Comment: isn't this browser error? show form code

Answer (score 0):

[BASE_PATH]\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php

```
return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
```

You can change or define **the custom message for authentication** in the above-given file path.
Change **Unauthorized** with custom message

Comment: the Authenticate.php doesn't exist in mentioned directory.

Comment: Please tell, which version are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, just know it's newer than 5.3

Comment: Thanks alot, its fixed my issue and saved my day @Ankit

Comment: I feels happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
you could create in app/http/Requests/filename.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class RegisterRequest extends RestFormRequest
{        
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email'     => 'required|email'    
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.required'    => 'Please Enter Email'               
        ];
    }  
}
```